# How can I make mongoose to validate an entire 'outdated' MongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

during the development of my app, i very often add custom and new fields to an existing schema, making the 'old' content in my mongodb 'incompelete' and missing the new fields. this leads sometimes to null content where it's required and it's in my use case very bad.

my question is what command/utility do i need to use to make mongoose validate my old documents, and in potential add those missing fields with pre-defined defaults to the old documents?

i remember reading something about that kind of functionality when i started learning how to use mongoose, but i just can't find it anywhere anymore..

thanks in advance :)

Amit

Comment: You "could" use ["discriminators"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) but that is going to require some extensive maintenance to mark the "old" and "new" types of objects to match an associated schema. Your general question is a bit broad and unclear as to what you actually want to do. Possibly all you really want to do is "Bulk Update" all the data to match the "current schema". But it's not really clear.

Comment: @NeilLunn excuse me for being unclear. suppose i have a `users` collection that contains basic fields such as `email`, `password`, `name` etc. during development i add a feature for counting `reputation` (just as a relatable example) to the `User` schema. now, when a client gets the whole `users` collection from the api, some documents contain the new `reputation` field and some don't. you get the idea. to bridge this issue, i know that mongoose offers a method that checks validity of old docs in the db, and sort of 'straighten the line' with the old docs by inserting default values.

Comment: @NeilLunn so my question is exactly - which method does that? i tried looking for it but couldn't find it anywhere, but i clearly remember seeing it in the mongoose docs.

Comment: Still incredibly unclear. Rather than trying to fit an explanation in "comments", use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36435194/edit) link on your question instead. Add document samples, showing small but relevant details and show exactly what you are trying to achieve and what problems you are having in your current handling.